# NullPointer ao utilizar Cucumber e Rest-Assured

Tags: java, rest, cucumber

Estou realizando um teste de API utilizando Cucumber e Rest-Assured, mas na chamada que utilizo o Rest-Assured está sendo retornado um `NullPointer`.

Minha Feature:

```
Scenario: Parâmetros não foram informados
Given A API de teste
When A requisição for realizada sem informar todos os parâmetros
Then A API deve retornar um status code 400
And uma mensagem de erro tratada
```

Parte da minha spec:

```
private Response response;
private ValidatableResponse json;
private RequestSpecification request;

private String ENDPOINT_POST = "https://api-api/algo";
private String TOKEN = "teste";
private String TYPE = "application/json";

@Given("^A API de teste$")
public void a_API_de_teste() {
    request = request.with().contentType(TYPE).header("Authorization", TOKEN);
}
```

No momento da execução do `@Given` está sendo retornado o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at steps.CenariosSteps.a_API(CenariosSteps.java:29)
>     at ?.Given A API de teste (/src/test/resources/features/cenarios.feature:5)

Eu não consegui ter ideia do que pode ser a causa, ainda porque o erro não parece 
estar estourando por completo.

Estou tentando seguir o exemplo do site:

> [Rest-Assured with Cucumber: Using BDD for Web Services Automation – Angie Jones](https://angiejones.tech/rest-assured-with-cucumber-using-bdd-for-web-/services-automation/)

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema alterando da seguinte maneira:

```
@Given("^A API de teste$")
public void a_API_de_teste() {
    request = RestAssured.with().contentType(TYPE).header("Authorization", TOKEN);
}
```